# Using node.js to listen for requests at specific URL (NOT LOCALHOST)

Tags: node.js, wordpress, woocommerce, webhooks

I am using a WordPress/WooCommerce webhook that is triggered when an order is updated.  The delivery address for the webhook is `example.com`.  After working the google for awhile, all the examples I saw involved localhost and none were listening to an alternate website such as `example.com`.  I want to use node.js to listen for POST requests at `example.com`.

I know that `example.com` is receiving the POST requests as expected, but I cannot view them through my node.js program.

```
let http = require('http');
let server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  if( req.method === 'POST' ) {
    console.log(req);
  } else {
    //do nothing
  }
});
server.listen('example.com');
```

When I run the above code it results in a permission denied error.  I do have permission to the server as it is my WordPress website, but I am not hosting the site on my machine, so I'm unsure how to access the requests.

The expected output is the full body of the HTTP POST request.  I want to console.log all POST requests that come to example.com

Comment: You can use free tools like [Ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) or [Local tunnel](https://localtunnel.github.io/www/) which can open your local port for all world.

Comment: When you start a webserver X, it can listen to the request received by the machine A in wich is running. If you want to receive on X the request (or part of them as you wish) direct to Y running on B, you should configure service Y to 'ping' X or the machine B to duplicate the request to X.

Comment: @AndreaFranchini So, if I have a wordpress server hosted on GoDaddy how can I create a Delivery URL for a webhook and listen to it from a node.js app?